# Can a Jedi mind trick work on another Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, jedi

Basically what the title says.  Is it possible for a Jedi to control another Jedi with a Jedi mind trick?  Or is that not possible?  Has this ever happened?

Comment: My personal impression is that the Jedi mind trick only works on characters without names in the script. It works on "Storm Trooper 2" or on "Drug Dealer", but not on "Watto".

Comment: One thing I don't think has ever been mentioned in canon is whether each user of a Jedi Mind Trick are equal or whether some can do more powerful Jedi Mind Tricks than others

Comment: It is possible. Obi-Wan set the rule: “weak-minded.” We see in PT that Jedi rules are made to be broken; if Anakin was “special” instead of older, Qui-Gon would still be dead set on training him because of belief in prophecy. Also given Jedi proclivity for losing limbs, head wounds may be commonplace, as is cognitive decline, so a once-strong-minded Jedi could easily have his condition change to weak-minded as time goes on.

Comment: @Philipp, aha, wrong! It also worked on Bib Fortuna. And based on the cringe-worthy dialogue, one suspects it was involved in the seduction of Padmé Amidala by the raging angst-monster that was Anakin. Because pretty much that's the only thing explaining why she was attracted to the whiny drama queen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it possible? Probably not. Has it happened? Not in canon, per se.

As Kenobi says after the first and possibly most famous use of the Jedi mind-trick, "The Force can have a powerful effect on the weak-minded." We don't really see any Force users who could be considered weak-minded.

All of the Jedi, Sith, and non-aligned Force users in canon have undergone training, and from what we see of that training it includes building up their mental fortitude. So it is unlikely such manipulation would be easy, and possibly downright impossible.

It's perhaps also the case that simply being Force sensitive would render someone immune to mind-control through the Force. Either through growing up more attuned to the world and people around them or simply that their connection to the Force gives them a natural protection. In Rebels, Kanan (jokingly) laments that he can't control Ezra using the Force.

> Ezra: "I wish that worked for me."
> Kanan: "I wish that worked *on* you."

Further to that, Kylo Ren's attempt at using a mind trick to force Rey to give up the details of the map in TFA failed. Although strong in the force, at that point Rey was completely untrained, and unaware of her Force sensitivity.

That being said, we do know that even trained Force users can be mislead by the use of Force powers by another. Such as Luke fooling Kylo Ren in TLJ.

> By appearing as a Force projection and delaying the First Order's assault on the remnants of the Resistance.

While that is not a simple suggestion along the lines of, "These are not the droids you're looking for," it might possibly count (even though it relies on a knowledge of weaknesses that you manipulate in your opponent).

Finally, and possibly off-topic, but during the opening of season 2 of Rebels, Vader uses the Force to control Ezra's arm, forcing him to hold his lightsaber to his own throat. While that's not mind control, it is using the Force to control the actions of another, partly-trained, Force wielder.

Comment: As an aside, I do believe there are instances in Legends where this defence against mind-tricks might have been a little looser. I think there's an example in the KOTOR games where a trained Force user is successfully mind-tricked, but for the life of me, I can't find it. The manipulation of Revan, post-amnesia _might_ count, possibly.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers have stated, one Jedi is not capable of Mind-Tricking another Jedi. *Multiple* Jedi, however, might be able to pull it off.

In the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode "Children of the Force", it's established that stronger-minded individuals *can* be Mind-Tricked if multiple Jedi attempt it at the same time. Specifically, Cad Bane is normally immune to Jedi Mind Tricks, yet Anakin, Obi-Wan, and Mace Windu are able to successfully Mind Trick him by working together.

It should be noted that the above process was extremely painful for Bane, bordering on torture, and (according to Obi-Wan) carried the risk of him losing his mind entirely. So under normal circumstances, it's not something that a group of Jedi would be *willing* to do, even if they would otherwise be able to. A group of Sith would, I'm sure, be willing to Mind Trick a Jedi, but the Sith historically lack both numbers and team-working skills, so the opportunity to do so has probably never presented itself.

Comment: While I accept that the potency of the mind-trick can be amplified by multiple Force-users acting in concert, there's no canon example of this being attempted on another Force-wielder. Cad Bane, while certainly strong-minded, showed no Force sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a Jedi, I would think not possible.

I watched all Star Wars movies + Mandalorian series.
Jedi suppose to mind-control those who have weaker/untrained minds.

In Episode 4: A New Hope, Obi Wan Kenobi said to Luke If I remember right that mind-control works on weaker mind. Usually.

In Episode 1: The Phantom Menace at the end Qui-Gon Jinn fights with Darth Maul that has red face with spikes. And he defeats him by hitting him in face with handle of his light saber and then quickly hitting him with light blade in chest.

Maul is suppose to draw power from The Dark Side of The Force.
And The Dark Side was said to be more powerful then Light Side.
So, if he is mentally more powerful he could just put his Light Side opponents to sleep and blow their heads off. But it doesn't happened.
In all Jedi vs Jedi fights that I've seen it doesn't happen.

In the end of the Episode 6: The Return of the Jedi, Luke Skywalker goes on board Death Star to try to turn his Farther Darth Vader to the Light Side.
Emperor offers him to serve him and he refuses.
Then Emperor makes him fight with Vader and Vader uses Force to make objects fly towards Luke. While being far superior to him in the Force and training he still can't affect him directly mind to mind.

At the end, Emperor tries to kill Luke using electricity discharges.And even that is not a direct Jedi Force vs Jedi Force in my opinion. It is using Force to generate a secondary medium - lighting bolts or to affect other Jedi physically. And only after doing it, Vader choose his side and tossed Emperor down some deep hole.

I think Great George Lucas when he was writing script for this, had pre-made it this way.
If Jedi can easily affect one another with their mind powers - it would be no fun.
Instead, we have nice light saber duels in several movies.

So, I think this can't happen.
Unless it be made in future movie/TV
But so far I haven't seen it anywhere.

Comment: Would you please explain you edited my answer? I have carefully checked grammar & spelling.